# (Node.js) How to get URL of a binary file stored in server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, url, digital-ocean

I am developing a service using node.js, which returns a url to a file stored in my service's database. In my program, I save the file to, for example, "./aFolder/filename.jpg". I'm going to use DigitalOcean. 
My questions are:
 1. What is the form of such a url?
 2. How can I get that url in my code using node.js?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Were you able to try my suggestion to enable your file downloads?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The URL will be whatever you want to make it since you'll presumably be the one writing the code to handle incoming requests.

Something like `http://uri/download/aFolder/filename.jpg` seems like a reasonable choice, but you'd need to write your app to accept those paths.

You may want to look into [Express](http://expressjs.com/) where you can add route handlers via [`app.route()`](http://expressjs.com/api.html#app.route) such that anything to `/download` gets processed by a particular callback that facilitates the mapping of the URL onto your filesystem and will likely be sending the correct file over using [`res.download()`](http://expressjs.com/api.html#res.download)

A basic skeleton might be:

```
app.route('/download:path')
.all(function(req, res, next) {
    res.download(req.params.path)
})
```

Comment: As a note, using the skeleton "as is" likely leads to remote file read vulnerability if dots (and possibly other special characters) are not filtered.